# SQLite incompatable database provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm having issues getting SQLite to work with the Entity Framework for Visual Studio 2017.  I had gotten it working in another project, and I thought I followed the same steps but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is the error message I get when trying to create an ADO.NET model:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit the wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action.

A quick checklist of things that are the same between the projects:

Common Nuget Packages:

- Entity Framework v6.2.0
- System.Data.SQLite.Core (v1.0.107 in working, v1.0.108 in the one that doesn't)
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6 (v1.0.107 in working, v1.0.108 in the one that doesn't)
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq (v1.0.107 in working, v1.0.108 in the one that doesn't)

Here is the Web.config from my working project (some data omitted to reduce size):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /><add description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

The non-working application's App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />

      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.MySql" type="Devart.Data.MySql.Entity.MySqlEntityProviderServices,       Devart.Data.MySql.Entity.EF6, Version=8.3.215.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

This is being done in the same installation of Visual Studio 2017.  The only thing I can think that is different is that SQLite came out with version 1.0.108 today and my other project uses 1.0.107.  I went and downloaded the new SQLite from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and no luck.  Here is my machine.config:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="dotConnect for SQLite" invariant="Devart.Data.SQLite" description="Devart dotConnect for SQLite" type="Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderFactory, Devart.Data.SQLite, Version=5.10.1086.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.108.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
```

I'm at a loss here.  I've banged my head against this all day and I don't know waht I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I have some tips here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: It seems like that worked although I'm not exactly sure why, which I don't intend as something against your guide.  I followed your steps to the T, that didn't work so I restarted my PC, tried again with no luck, and then recreated the connection to my database and now it passed through.  Maybe something was off in the way I created the database connection before.  Anyway, thank you very much for your guide.